# C#: How can I copy an azure storage blob from one account to another cross-tenant?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I know azcopy works cross tenant but I'd need to copy a blob from one storage account to another in a different tenant via C# in my case. Will this library work? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-data-movement-library#copy-a-blob

Or will the storage sdk's StartCopyFromUriAsync work fine? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/copy-blob?tabs=azure-ad

I can't find any references on cross-tenant blob copy compatibility for either sdk online, only for the powershell azcopy cmdlet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With below **C#** code, I can able to copy an azure storage blob from one account to another cross-tenant.

```cs
{
            CloudStorageAccount sourceAccount =CloudStorageAccount.Parse("Source_conne_tring");
            CloudStorageAccount destinationAccount =CloudStorageAccount.Parse("destination_conne_string");
            CloudBlobClient sourceClient = sourceAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlob sourceBlob = sourceClient.GetBlobReferenceFromServer(new Uri("https://source_account.blob.core.windows.net/container/blob")) as CloudBlob;
            CloudBlobClient destinationClient = destinationAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlob destinationBlob = destinationClient.GetBlobReferenceFromServer(new Uri("https://destination_account.blob.core.windows.net/container/blob")) as CloudBlob;

            Task copyTask = TransferManager.CopyAsync(sourceBlob, destinationBlob, true, null, null);
            await copyTask;
            Console.WriteLine("Successfully copied the blob.");
        }
    }
```

Reference :   [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-data-movement-library)

**Output:**
[image]

**Portal Output:**
Successfully uploaded blob
[image]